# Authentication web service and special characters in password

Tags: web-services, authentication, password

My client application is authenticating with a SharePoint website using the [Authentication web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/authentication%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0. The client is not written in C# and I craft the SOAP request "manually".

The authentication fails with the `PasswordNotMatch` LoginErrorCode when the provided password contains special characters. For instance, this password `xS-5[V!VQEo!-4` generated by SharePoint fails the authentication.

What kind of encoding/escaping/processing do I need to do on the password when I build the SOAP request for authentication? Here's an example request with the password mentioned above:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<soap:Body>
<Login xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
<username>my.username</username>
<password>xS-5[V!VQEo!-4</password>
</Login>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Comment: OK, actually, the password I've given doesn't fail authentication. But I guess XML reserved characters would not be accepted, would they?

Comment: It seems very likely that you would need to encode XML reserved characters: `<>"&`

Comment: Hi Kit, yes probably but into what? Their corresponding entity?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you figured it out already but I'm guessing it is the [XML reserved characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
< becomes &lt;
> becomes &gt;
& becomes &amp;
" becomes &quot;
' becomes &apos;
```

Really though, whatever language you're crafting the SOAP message in probably already has a HTML/XML encode function.

More information and a [list of all the entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).